# isDisplayed() returning null pointer exception on 3.12.0 selenium jars

Tags: selenium

Recently I have upgraded our selenium project to 3.12.0 jars. element.isDisplayed()  is returning null pointer exception where it is working well on my old binaries 2.53.0

InternetExplorer 3.12 used against jars 3.12.0

InternetExplorer 2.46 used against jars 2.53.0

Our application only works on IE, so I didn't tried this on remaining browsers

Comment: Can u add the relevant code?

Comment: return type of IsDisplayed method is boolean. It should return either true or false. May be the element is null. please check the element is null or not.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)